# Leiningen installing error?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, leiningen

Today when I finshed install Leiningen
The below error shows up.
What is wrong 
and how to fix this !

[image]

Comment: How did you install Leiningen?

Comment: just use windows installer!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the leiningen's jar has not been downloaded. You can try to install manually:

```
1. download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein.bat

2. lein.bat self-install
```

It should show the download of the jar.

Comment: Why is it obvious? Does installing `lein` include installing Clojure?

Comment: The error: could not find or load main class clojure.main that the  uberjar is not available.

Comment: I would have thought that `clojure.main` was in a Clojure jar file, nothing to do with lein. Also they are all just jar files (uberjar makes little sense to me here).

Comment: @Chris Murphy I just took a look at the lein script (https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/bin/lein#L351) and saw that this script just starts the leiningen's jar in the background.

Comment: This is a Windows question so you should be looking at the batch file: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/bin/lein.bat.

Comment: Ups, thanks and sorry for my mistake. In the bat file i saw the same structure: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/bin/lein.bat#L380

Comment: We know that the classpath does not contain `clojure.main`. It still could contain `leiningen.core.main`. OP could print out %CLASSPATH% and see which jars are there and add that to the question.